# How to fix this ImportError: No module named win32api? (win32api path variable)

Tags: python, winapi, path, environment-variables, bioinformatics

I'm new to programming and computer world. I'm trying to study biomolecular simulations with MMTK.

I run it in Windows 7 and I have already installed this software:

- python-2.5.4
- numpy-1.6.2-win32-superpack-python2.5
- netCDF4-0.8.2.win32-py2.5
- ScientificPython-2.9.0.win32-py2.5
- MMTK-2.6.0.win32-py2.5

When I run this [protein.py](http://structure.usc.edu/mmtk/Examples/MolecularDynamics/protein.py) mmtk sample, all seems to be OK. It show the numbers of 1000 process steps.

But when I run a script with `view` method, like this:

```
from MMTK import *
molecule = Molecule('water')
molecule.view()
```

Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\BIOCHEM\Desktop\mmtk\mmtk_water.py", line 4, in <module>
molecule.view()
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\MMTK\Collections.py", line 495, in view
Visualization.viewConfiguration(self, configuration, format)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\MMTK\Visualization.py", line 263, in viewConfiguration
function(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\MMTK\Visualization.py", line 236, in genericViewConfiguration
import win32api
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

After searching for some answers on the internet (mainly this one: http://www.varioustopics.com/python/142947-importerror-no-module-named-win32api.html), I came to the conclusion that this is a problem in the **path environment variables**. Unfortunately, the answer to this question doesn't present details. And I need a **detailed** answer.
This issue of the environment variables seems so simple to me as the mystery of life's emergence on Earth. I know how to change it, but I don't know **what** to change or **when** change it. Reading the Wikipedia articles on the subject didn't help me too much.
So what I'd like to know is: how exactly to modify the system variable in **this** case? I must add a new variable or just one more path to an existing variable? What is the path to win32api (it should not be C:\Windows\System32)?

This is my current variable value:

Variable's name:
    Path

Variables's value:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%PYTHON_HOME%;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86);C:\Python27\; C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python25\DLLs
```

I also have this Python variable: `PYTHON_HOME` with this variable's value: `C:\Python27`

This question may seem trivial to an experienced programmer. But the answer to it can be very useful to others. There is a large number of biologists, biochemists and pharmacists interested in using computational methods to their problems. These professionals do not always have a computer scientist in the vicinity (especially if they are in an underdeveloped country).

Overcoming this initial frustrating phase of bugs and installation problems can be crucial in the scientific career of many people. And the answer to this question will help them.

Thanks in advance. If this forum is not appropriate for questions of this level, please give me a feedback.

Comment: For me, restarting Windows solved this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install pywin32 or ActivePython.

Comment: Right. Win32api isn't part of the standard Python install; modifying the path won't help you to find something that isn't there.

Comment: Thanks, Ignacio and Mark. So that explains the mystery of the missing path. Now I'm getting this another error: "There is no program associated with ..pdb files, please install a suitable viewer" . I found this information: "A viewer for PDB files can be defined by the environment variable PDBVIEWER. For showing a PDB file, MMTK will execute a command consisting of the value of this variable followed by a space and the name of the PDB file." But now my doubt is: how define a viewer for PDB files by the environment variable PDBVIEWER? What would be the variable value?

Comment: sounds like you might want to check out the RCSB protein data bank website